# Numerical way to deal with Dirac delta.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dirac-delta

I have been wondering about this:

I have a differential equation $y'(t) = y(t) + n \delta(t) y(t)$ with $y(-1) :=y_0$

Thus I want to apply a short delta pulse at some particular point $0$ to my system with a strength controlled by some sort of coefficient $n$. My question is: How do I simulate this numerically?- If I want to apply some canonical numerical ODE solver to this ODE( is this even possible here?).

Comment: Use a Gaussian function to model the pulse.

Comment: I'm afraid I am not aware of any other method than adapting the mesh and the pulse width. You can compare your results with the analytical solution, which I figure it can be obtained relatively easy. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deal with these type of questions, it is best to treat the delta function as zero everywhere, that is to solve $y'(t) = y(t)$ with $y( - 1) = {y_0}$. But the effect of the delta is that your solution step should break at $t=0$. Actually by integrating the equation on a small domain around $t=0$ you could see that $$y({0^ + }) = y({0^ - }) + ny(0)$$ which is again equivalent to $y'(t) = ny(t)\delta (t)$ (notice that we are examining the dynamic of the equation in very small times around the origin). Now, the solution in this small domain for $\varepsilon  > 0$ is $y(t) = y( - \varepsilon ){e^{nU(t)}}$, which gives $y({0^ + }) = {e^n}y({0^ - })$.Summarizing, you should solve your main equation until $t=0$, then having these solutions you should solve $$\begin{array}{l}y'(t) = y(t)\\y({0^ + }) = {e^n}y({0^ - })\end{array}$$ for $t>0$.

Comment: This is an interesting answer. Do you have a reference for this method or does it have a name? Do you think that the method suggested in the comments gives similar results?

Comment: @TobiasHurth I don't remember a reference or name but this is a standard method which we used for solving our PDEs, with say point sources (which are modeled by Dirac's delta). And yes, I am pretty sure that the method which is described in the comments should also yield the same result. However, that method, as you have pointed out, has some numerical drawbacks and is best suited to give your ODE a meaning (in the theoretical sense). Good luck ;)

Comment: sorry, when you integrate. what happens to $\int y(t) dt $? Apparently it is zero, but why?

Comment: @TobiasHurth are you sure you have typed the question correctly (it has no time derivative)

Comment: @TobiasHurth if the functions magnitude is bounded near the origin (if it does not blow up), apparently the width could be chosen such that its integral vanishes. Now, since uniqueness is presumed for your question, we assume that the solution is bounded and attempt to find one. If it is found, it is the only solution.

Comment: @TobiasHurth it seems that your trying to solve Schrodinger's equation. Anyhow, it is the same thing here. In this case, you have $$i\left( {\psi (x,{0^ + }) - \psi (x,{0^ - })} \right) = n\left( {\frac{{\psi (x,{0^ + }) + \psi (x,{0^ - })}}{2}} \right)$$ which assuming you have already obtained numerical solutions for $t<0$ gives a new "initial condition" for the PDE for $t>0$

Comment: thank you very much. yes, indeed I am. :-)

Comment: @TobiasHurth Sorry, it seems that your question was quite different from what I had seen before. There as I said, the Dirac was in the inhomogeneous term, hence the dynamic of the system was not affected. For your question, the system has a dynamic, which is characterized by the length of your approximation to the delta function. Anyhow, you could solve the simple resultant first order ODE (for any $x$) to see that $\psi (x,{0^ + }) = {e^{ - in}}\psi (x,{0^ - })$. Note that I have also edited the answer to correct this error.

Comment: @ did you check this somewhere or did you figure this out by yourself. I am asking, cause I would still appreciate a reference ( not because I don't trust you, but because I would like to read about it)

Comment: @TobiasHurth I checked the answers with Mathematica.

Comment: @TobiasHurth I was not quite satisfied with the part of my answer which I replaced the average of the left and right values of the function instead of the value at the origin. So, I checked to see if there were any analytical answers to your question. Fortunately, Mathematica gave it as $y(t) = {y_{ - 1}}{e^{1 + t + nU(t)}}$, which I immediately recognized that could have been obtained using the integrating factor technique for first order ODEs in the first place. Anyhow, this was different from what I posted earlier which triggered my curiosity to find the root of the error and correct it.

Comment: sorry, this might be a stupid question now, but do you say that this is the actual solution to the problem? You expressed the a solution in this small regime in terms of some function $U$, that I don't know. I mean if we have an eigenfunction $\psi(x,t)$ that fulfills $i \partial_t \psi(x,t) = -\partial_x^2 \psi(x,t)$ and apply now at $t=0$ the pulse, so that we get a new problem with $\psi(x,0^+) = e^{-in}\psi(x,0^-)$. How does this one satisfy $i \partial_t \psi(x,0) = -\partial_x^2 \psi(x,0)+n  \delta(t) \psi(x,0)$?

Comment: @TobiasHurth First note that by $U$ I meant the unit step function. Second, the idea behind the method I described is that when the Dirac delta is not zero (that is in a loose sense in a vanishingly small region around the origin), it is so large in magnitude that all the other terms could be neglected in comparison. Now, by this, the second derivative could be neglected in magnitude in the small region near $t=0$ which leaves us with a first order ODE which we could easily solve. I hope you get the idea ;)

Comment: yes, thanks....

Answer (score 1):

A dirac delta functions can be modelled numerically using a box-car function with width approaching a small number, and it can also be modelled using a gaussian with half-width approaching a small value. In general, you model a dirac delta in space with box-car and time with gaussian !