# Pure numerical solution of ODE with impulsive terms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dirac-delta

Consider an ODE in the form:

$$\dot{y} = f(y) + \alpha \delta(t - t_0)$$

for some $t_0 \geq 0$.

I know that the standard way to solve it numerically is to transform the ODE in order to turn the effect of Dirac delta into initial conditions (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121905/numerical-solution-of-ode-with-delta-function) for example).

Anyway, I was wondering if there is a **pure** numerical way to solve this kind of problem. Indeed, consider a real world situation in which the system is modeled as:

$$\dot{y} = f(y) + \alpha u(t),$$

where $u(t)$ is some exogenous input which is not known *a priori* (e.g. a steady current which suddenly becomes impulsive, a steady market and then a shock, the sudden spread of a disease...).

How can we solve numerically the system provided that $u(t)$ is not known and it may also contains impulsive terms **without** reformulating the ODE based on the knowledge of $u(t)$?

Comment: How would you encode such an input signal with delta pulses in a numerical framework?

Comment: @LutzLehmann my question is ... about your question

Comment: One has to specifically note down the time and factor, then integrate to this time, change the state and continue with the new initial conditions. There is no way to represent non-regular distributions like normal function evaluation procedures. One can of course also use approximations by large pulses. But this destroys the regularity of the ODE so that interrupting and restarting is again the cleaner solution. Some solver packages implement an event-action-callback which does this "behind the scenes".

Comment: @LutzLehmann thanks